# Доступ к стандартным иконкам swing

Tags: icon, swing

Здравствуйте!
Как в swing получить доступ к стандартной иконке (к той, которая выводится в диалогах из JOptionPane), чтобы использовать ее в своем диалоге.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот, только по исходникам разобрался. Это делается так:

```
Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
```